# Anyway to do MongoDB Sharding in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, bigdata, nosql

I have started using MongoDB for one of my PHP project. In that database, i am trying to use MongoDB sharding concept. I got the below link and tried,

[MongoDB Sharding Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552187/mongodb-sharding-example)

It is working well. But the problem is, in the above example, everything is done in command prompt. But i am trying to do everything in PHP. I am not able to get any example in PHP.

So far, i have started with these piece of codes,

```
    $connection =   new Mongo();
    $db     =   $connection->selectDB('TestDB');
    $db     =   $connection->TestDB;

    $connection->selectDB('admin')->command(array('addshard'=>'host:port'));
    $connection->selectDB('admin')->command(array('enablesharding'=>'TestDB'));
    $connection->selectDB('admin')->command(array('shardcollection'=>'TestDB.large', 'key' => '_id'));
```

It is not working. Also, i dont know how to set shard servers and config database in PHP.

Is there any other way to do MongoDB sharding in PHP?

Comment: You can do it in PHP sending database commands down to mongodb but why would you wanna do it in PHP? Sharding is a complicated procedure that requires a lot of work on the admin side both in the mongodb shell and physically on the servers themselves, I think you are looking at the wrong thing by asking this

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks for replying. The problem is, we have so many servers like test, demo and production. If i have a php script, i can run anytime wherever i need sharding. I can execute in all servers by simply making the server configuration. Thats why i am looking for that

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB's database commands are case-sensitive. You were passing in lowercase command names, while the real commands are camelCased (see: [sharding commands](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/nav-sharding/)). Additionally, the `key` paremeter of `shardCollection` needs to be an object.

A corrected version of your above code would look like:

```
$connection->selectDB('admin')->command(array('addShard'=>'host:port'));
$connection->selectDB('admin')->command(array('enableSharding'=>'TestDB'));
$connection->selectDB('admin')->command(array('shardCollection'=>'TestDB.large', 'key' => array('_id' => 1)));
```

Additionally, you should have been able to examine the command result of to determine why this wasn't working. The `ok` field would be zero, and an `errmsg` field would explain the error (e.g. "no such cmd: addshard").

Lastly, if you're attempting to mimic the shell's functionality to configure sharding in PHP, you may realize that some of the [shell methods](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sharding-commands/) are more than just database commands. For any of those methods, you can get the JS source by omitting the parentheses. For example:

```
> sh.addTagRange
function ( ns, min, max, tag ) {
    var config = db.getSisterDB( "config" );
    config.tags.update( {_id: { ns : ns , min : min } } ,
            {_id: { ns : ns , min : min }, ns : ns , min : min , max : max , tag : tag } ,
            true );
    sh._checkLastError( config );
}
```

That would be a useful hint for what an `addTagRange()` function in PHP would need to do.