# MongoDB: drop sharded collection error

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I use the current MongoDB version on linux.
I have a sharded replica set and a testscript for inserting data and deleting data (in javascript).

By dropping the sharded collection it says:
"errmsg" : "exception: collection's metadata is undergoing changes. Please try again."

I read:
http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongodb-user/128v9ad20k/drop-sharded-collection-error-exception-collections-metadata-is-undergoing-changes-please-try-again

and

[mongoDB sharding example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552187/mongodb-sharding-example/8557168#8557168)

but I didn't get any further.